# GridView will not display when button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, vbscript

I have an ASP.NET page I am writing in VB, and I am trying to only have the gridView show up when the button is clicked, and that it should display the product id, product name, supplier name, and quantity purchased for all products purchased by the customer (which comes from the drop down list). For some reason that I am unable to figure out, no matter what I do the gridView does not display. Ever. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyName] FROM [Customers] ORDER BY [CompanyName]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Customers_1.CustomerID, Customers_1.CompanyName, (SELECT COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID WHERE (Customers.CompanyName = @p1)) AS [Number of Orders], SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice * [Order Details].Quantity - [Order Details].Discount) AS [Total Cost of Order] FROM Customers AS Customers_1 INNER JOIN Orders AS Orders_1 ON Customers_1.CustomerID = Orders_1.CustomerID INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders_1.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID WHERE (Customers_1.CompanyName = @p1) GROUP BY Customers_1.CustomerID, Customers_1.CompanyName">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="p1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName, Suppliers.CompanyName, [Order Details].Quantity FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID WHERE (Customers.CustomerID = @p1)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="p1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyName">
            <asp:ListItem>Select A Customer</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Number of Orders" HeaderText="Number of Orders" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Number of Orders" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total Cost of Order" HeaderText="Total Cost of Order" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Total Cost of Order" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" EmptyDataText="N/A" Visible="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Order Summary" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my code-behind page looks like this:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GridView1.Visible = True
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource3"
        GridView1.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: last line should be GridView1.DataBind()

Comment: Thank you! @DenisWessels

Comment: I've posted as an answer.Please mark as answered if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `DataSource` or `DataSourceID` property of the `GridView` you need to call [DataBind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) as a final step to bind your grid to the data.